# UICollectionView dynamic width based on number of items inside it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm currently wanna create an floating UICollectionView on screen which can change width whenever number of items inside it changed. 
For example:
I'm prefer to make it with max width = 280px
If `numberOfItems` = 2, my UICollectionView width will fit with items inside it, and it will increase width till `numberOfItems` = 4, If `numberOfItems` > 4, it's will enable scrolling horizontally.
Does someone has made it before? Please help me.
Thanks in advance.
edit: I'm updated image about the collection view, currently it's only have 2 items while width = 280.
[image]

Comment: could you provide screen shot of demo image.

Comment: @PhaniRaghu I'm updated the image and this is a floating collection view on screen so I'm not using autolayout.

Comment: I already answered for height. Same thing apply to width.

Comment: I don't using auto layouts, can your solution work with my case?

Comment: That is easy solution with auto layouts. Without auto layouts its not worked. But if you doing this programatically, then also you can follow the same conditions. But instead of changing width you need to change frame.

Comment: Sure, I did it with set frame instead.

Comment: Son Is it worked?

Comment: @PhaniRaghu Yeah, It's worked.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I think that is something you are looking for. Check out my [test project](https://github.com/1mperial8e/DynamicCollectionViewSize) to see how it works.
You have to change width constraint only.

Comment: In this case, I'm created this collectionview programmatically and doesn't use auto layout for it, so I can connect an outlet for width constraint. Do you have another solution? But still thank you for the example.

Comment: No problems with that, then you should calculate CollectionView frame and animate it inside UIView animation block.